# How to use Pause in gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to use `normalPausesWithPercentageDuration` **where do I declare it and use it** in my gatling script. Any examples how to use it will be more helpful?

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class temp extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL(testServerUrl)

    val scn = scenario("Test data")
        .feed(csvFeeder)
        .exec(http("My Request")
            .get("""/api/xyz/${ID}""")
            )

        .normalPausesWithPercentageDuration(2) // This is not working

    setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(userCount) during(duration minutes))).protocols(httpProtocol)

}
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to pause ,some other useful code as well

```
    exec( http("Poll")
      .get(Configuration.URL)
      .queryParam("requestor", "TEST")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(status.saveAs("statusCode"))
      .check(xpath("//status").saveAs("responseStatus"))
     )
    .pause(Configuration.THINK_TIME second)
```